# check if DSQuery was successful in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory, windows-scripting

I'm trying to convert a batch script to PowerShell. I encountered this piece of code, can anyone tell me how to convert this to PowerShell?

```
dsquery ou -domain "$SysDomain" -name "$FuncOU,$DestOU" || (echo OU was not found & Goto :eof)
```

I want to do somnething like:

```
$dsq = dsquery ou -domain "$SysDomain" -name "$FuncOU,$DestOU"
if ($dsq.HasSucceeded -eq $true) {
    echo "OU was not found"
    exit
}
```

Comment: Use proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dsquery` doesn't return an exit code, so I doubt that your batch command could ever have worked. Also, the command produces string output, not a process or job object, so there's no `HasSucceeded` property to check.

What you can do is check the output of the command that is collected in the variable `$dsq`. If the variable is empty, the command did not find a OU. PowerShell [automatically interprets `$null` values as `$false`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx), so something like this should work:

```
$dsq = & dsquery ou ...
if (-not $dsq) {
    echo 'OU was not found.'
    exit 1
}
```

**Side note:** I recommend using the call operator (`&`) for running external commands, and returning an actual exit code when using the `exit` statement.